# Filebeat/Logstash Multiline Syslog Parsing

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am parsing the syslog into the ELK-stack.
Syslog example

`Jul 19 10:47:21 host-abc systemd: Started myservice
Jul 19 10:47:29 host-abc systemd: Started service.
Jul 19 10:47:29 host-abc systemd: Starting service...`

What ideally would like to do is to aggregate the 2nd and third line into one message,for example returning: `Started Service. Starting service...`
therefore I would like the timestamp, hostname and program name to match before the lines are combined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`aggregate`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-aggregate.html#plugins-filters-aggregate-example3) filter in order to achieve what you want. The `aggregate` filter provides support for aggregating several log lines into one single event based on a common field value. In your case, the common field would be a combination of `@timestamp`, `hostname` and `program_name`.

Since the `syslog` input is already properly parsing the syslog lines, we don't need to grok anything, so we can leverage the `aggregate` filter immediately. We aggregate the lines based on the `SYSLOGBASE2` field which will contain everything up to the colon character `:`. Then we simply gather all messages and finally we join the messages into a string. It goes like this:

```
input {
  syslog {
    ...
  }
}
filter {
  aggregate {
    task_id => "%{SYSLOGBASE2}"
    code => "map['message'] ||= []; map['message'].push(event.get('message'));"
    push_map_as_event_on_timeout => true
    timeout_task_id_field => "user_id"
    timeout => 1 # 1 second timeout
    timeout_tags => ['_aggregatetimeout']
    timeout_code => "event.set('message', map['message'].join(' '))"
  }
}
output {
  ...
}
```